# Adding and removing UITableViewCell below a certain UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to have a tableview where there is a subclass of uitableviewcell(cell1) that contains a button among other things. This button is supposed to add and remove a different subclass of uitableviewcell(cell2) directly below it when the button is clicked in cell1. I've attached a pretty poor illustration of what I want to happen.[image]

What I have tried to do is when the button is tapped I insert cell2 into the array of cell objects at array[indexPath.row+1] of cell1 and then remove that object from the array when you tap to close the cell. After I insert or remove the cell I reload the tableView to update it to reflect the array, however this is where it screws up and doesn't behave as I believe it should. Code below to give a better picture:

```
var tableCellObjects: [NSObject] = [] //grab the cell objects from an API call and append the cell2Object when a cell1 is expanded


func moreButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    var indexPath: NSIndexPath!

    if let superview = sender.superview {
        if let cell = superview.superview as? Cell1 {
            indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        }
    }

    if tableCellObjects[sender.tag].isKindOfClass(Cell1Object) {
        let cell1Object = tableCellObjects[sender.tag] as! Cell1Object

        if cell1Object.expanded {
            cell1Object.expanded = false
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "MoreButtonClosed.png"), forState: .Normal)
            tableCellObjects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row+1)

            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            cell1Object.expanded = true
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "MoreButtonOpen.png"), forState: .Normal)
            tableCellObjects.insert(Cell2Object(param1, param2: param2), atIndex: indexPath.row+1)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Simple question with plenty of code. Please just post the key code.

Comment: I deleted what seemed like fluff code. What is left is my function for adding / removing the cells. Is that what you meant by key code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your data changes, you should update data source and then insert/delete/reload index paths. Use following functions:

```
public func insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
public func deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
public func reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

And I suggest you use `.Fade` to make animation smooth.